# Variable not updated on AsyncTask

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-asynctask

Like title says, my variable is not updated on `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute()`

Here is the code

```java
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<paire> Sectors = new ArrayList<paire>();//paire is my proper class
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    Rechercher rech = new Rechercher();
    rech.execute();
    //PRINTING SIZE OF Sectors HERE TELLS ME EXACTLY THE SIZE OF 0

    /*
    *
    *
    BLA BLA BLA BLA
    *
    *
    */
}

 public class Rechercher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<paire>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<paire>doInBackground(String... strings) {
        /*
        *
        Process of creating the arrayList myArray

        *
        */
        onPostExecute(myArray);//I put this desesperatly xD it doesn't change anything

        return myArray;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<paire>myArray) {
        for (int u = 0; u < myArray.size(); u ++){
                paire r = myArray.get(u);
                Sectors.add(r);
            }
        //PRINTING SIZE OF Sectors HERE TELLS ME EXACTLY THE SIZE OF myArray
    }

}
}
```

Well `myArray` is created from data gotten from dataBase (HTTP connection, JSON result ...) and the result is a very acceptable JSON output; there's no problem here, it's just that `Sectors` is not updated if I try to use it on Main.
I don't know if I really understand the onPostExecute; or there's a problem !
Thank you

Comment: I think you are confused by the notion of the asynctask being executed asynchronously. You would see how it is scheduled if you ran your code in debug mode and placed breakpoints in your various methods.

Answer (score 1):

`onPostExcecute`   will call automatically just return your array in `doBackground`  and pass ArrayList instead of void in  `AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<paire>>` and change return type of `doInBackground` to `ArrayList<paire>`

try this:

```
public class Rechercher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<paire>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<paire> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            /*
            *
            Process of creating the arrayList myArray

            *
            */
            //onPostExecute(myArray); // remove this line no need to add . this will call automatically.
            return myArray;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<paire> myArray) {
            for (int u = 0; u < s.size(); u ++){
                Sectors.set(u, s.get(u));
            }
            //PRINTING SIZE OF Sectors HERE TELLS ME EXACTLY THE SIZE OF myArray
        }

    }
```

hope this help.

Comment: ohk :) you are retuning myArray instead of null right?

Comment: If you did it, I did it, this is what the copy/past :(

Comment: ya i know . just want to confirm to solve problem you know. can you please add your updated snippet.

Comment: `@Override
        protected ArrayList<paire> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            /*
   *
   LOT OF BLABLA ABOUT CREATING myArray
   *
   */

            return myArray;
        }`

Comment: debug and check your array here  return myArray;  is it having value or not? because all is looking good . and if you upate your question with updated snippet that will be very helpful.

Comment: have you debug and check whether your array having value when you set in doinbackground

Comment: All seems okay, I got 14 items in myArray, also in Sectors when in onPostExecute; but when I go in main, Sectors is empty even after AsyncTask !

Comment: Ok, ok ok ok ok ! BUT ?
This drives me crasy xD

Answer (score 0):

Is this building without errors?  I dont believe that you can call onPostExecute from doInBackground and I dont see anywhere in the code where there is a variable called "s" but s.size() is what is controlling the number of times the for loop iterates.  So in the current code, Sectors.set would never be called.

Answer (score 0):

you should read careful about asyncTask again.
Modify you asynTask as below

```
public class Rechercher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<paire>>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
    /*
    *
    Process of creating the arrayList myArray

    *
    */
    /* don't need to call this function, asynctask will call it automatically
        onPostExecute(myArray);
    */
    return myArray;
}
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<paire>myArray) {

    if (Selector.size() > 0) {
        Selector.clear();
    }
    for (int u = 0; u < s.size(); u ++){
        Sectors.add(s.get(u));
    }
            //PRINTING SIZE OF Sectors HERE TELLS ME EXACTLY THE SIZE OF myArray
}
}
```

Comment: `code Error:(164, 20) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Search.paire> cannot be converted to Void`
Just in return's line

Comment: Yah; and also `codeprotected ArrayList<paire> doInBackground(String... strings)` but the size after executing Rech is always 0 :(

Comment: could you check that after doInBackground executed,  myArray.size() > 0 or not

Comment: Yes it's 14; and as I said, printing Sector's size in onPostExecute told me 14 !

Comment: I change my answer again, could you check it one more time?

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was about the empty arrayList, but I got always 0 size in the main !

Comment: So you should post your all implementation

Comment: Do you think it's useful; I choosed the concerned lines so people can get what I mean; but if you think posting everything helps; here we go for next answer (:

Answer (score 0):

```
package caci.elmouchir;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

    private void setSectors(String[] lesSec){
        Spinner sec = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSecteur);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lesSec);
        sec.setAdapter(adapter);

        sec.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
    ArrayList<paire> Sectors = new ArrayList<paire>();
    ArrayList<paire> Branchs = new ArrayList<paire>();
    ArrayList<paire> SBranchs = new ArrayList<paire>();
    ArrayList<paire> Activities = new ArrayList<paire>();





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        String Code = "X.XX.XX.XXX";
        Rechercher rech = new Rechercher();
        rech.execute();
        Log.e("log_tag", Integer.toString(Sectors.size()));
        //Log.e("log_tag", Integer.toString(Sectors.size()));






        Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText motcle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editMotCle);
                if (motcle.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    motcle.setError("Entrez un mot clé");
            }
        });

        /*
        *
        *
        *
        *
        C O N N E X I O N                   A              L A                B A S E               D E                  D O N N E E S
        *
        *
        *
        *
        */


    }


    public class Rechercher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<paire>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<paire> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            ArrayList<paire> s = new ArrayList<paire>();
            try{

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.145/test/getActivities.php");
                //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                //convert response to string
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
                //Log.e("log_tag", result);
                try{

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    ArrayList<paire> b = new ArrayList<paire>();
                    ArrayList<paire> sous = new ArrayList<paire>();
                    ArrayList<paire> a = new ArrayList<paire>();

                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = (JSONObject)jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString().length() == 2){
                            paire p = new paire(json_data.getString("title").toString(),json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString());
                            s.add(p);


                        }
                        else if(json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString().length() == 3){
                            b.add(new paire(json_data.getString("title").toString(),json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString()));
                        }
                        else if(json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString().length() == 4){
                            sous.add(new paire(json_data.getString("title").toString(),json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString()));
                        }
                        else{
                            a.add(new paire(json_data.getString("title").toString(),json_data.getString("friendly_url").toString()));
                        }}
                    //Log.e("log_tag", Integer.toString(s.size()));

                   // onPostExecute(s, b, sous, a);



                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }


            return s;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<paire>s) {
            /*Sectors = s;
            Branchs = b;
            SBranchs = sous;
            Activities = a;*/


                for (int u = 0; u < s.size(); u ++){
                    paire r = s.get(u);
                    Sectors.add(r);
                }
            Log.e("log_tag", "loool: "+Integer.toString(Sectors.size()));

        }

    }


    public class paire{
        String title;
        String url;
        paire(String p, String u){
            this.title = p;
            this.url = u;
        }
        String getTitle(){
            return this.title;
        }
        String getUrl(){
            return this.url;
        }
    }
}
```